# Filter list of maps by value and return map

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

If I have a `List<Map<String, String>>` object such as this `currencyList` :

```
0
   0 = "product_id" -> 145
   1 = "currency" -> USD
1
   0 = "product_id" -> 105
   1 = "currency" -> EUR
2
   0 = "product_id" -> 102
   1 = "currency" -> EUR
```

How do I then filter where `currency=EUR`?

Something like...

```
List<Map<String, String>> eurCurrencyList 
             = currencyList.stream()
                           .anyMatch(map -> map.containsValue("EUR"));
```

but that doesn't return a `boolean` but returns a `map` like this:

```
0
   0 = "product_id" -> 105
   1 = "currency" -> EUR
1
   0 = "product_id" -> 102
   1 = "currency" -> EUR
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I then filter where **currency**=**EUR**?

You have to use `filter` like so :

```
String key = "currency", value = "EUR";
List<Map<String, String>> eurCurrencyList = currencyList.stream()
        .filter(map -> map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).equals(value))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note, Instead of :

```
map.containsValue("EUR")
```

You have to use :

```
.filter(map -> map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).equals(value))
```

You have to check if the map contain that key and the value.

Comment: Just curious: *Why* is `.get().equals()` better than `.containsValue()`

Comment: @Lino note that the OP want the key `currency` and the value `EUR` so if you make `map.containsValue("EUR")` that will work also if the key is not `currency`

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `filter` to filter and can collect to list using `Collectors.toList()`.

```
List<Map<String, String>> eurCurrencyList = currencyList.stream()
        .filter(map -> map.containsValue("EUR"))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

**EDIT:**

If the map can have many entries, it may be inefficient to use `containsValue`. Instead you can do `.filter(map -> map.containsKey(key) && map.get(key).equals(value))` as mentioned in [YCF_L@'s answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50676803/4405757).

Comment: @YCF_L Or even `map.getOrDefault(key, "").equals(value)`